# Write $1/1 + 1/2 + ...1/ (p-1)=a/b$ with $(a,b)=1$. Show that $p^2 \mid a$ if $p\geq 5$ is prime [Wolstenholme's theorem]

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Write $\frac 11 + \frac12 + ...\frac1{(p-1)} =$ $\frac ab$.Such that $(a,b)=1$. Show that $p^2 \mid a$ $\text{if}$ $p\geq 5$.

I was trying to apply something with prime modulus, but I am unsure how exactly to go about it.

Comment: There's probably a typo somewhere, since there's no way that $\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{p-1}$ equals 1 if $p$ isn't 2.

Comment: @DennisMeng Fixed.

Comment: Still a little hesitant, since it looks like $\frac{a}{b}$ got added by someone other than the question asker.

Comment: @DennisMeng The way the problem is written now seems true by a little experimentation

Comment: Whether or not the problem as currently written is true or not isn't my concern. My concern is whether or not this is the actual problem that the original poster wanted to ask in the first place.

Comment: This is called Wolstenholme's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem (or at least half of it)

Comment: This amounts to proving that the coefficient of $x$ when you expand $(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-(p-1))$ is divisible by $p^2$. Not sure if that helps any.

Comment: Note that you can clear fractions by multiplying by $(p-1)!$, which does not involve changing divisibility by $p$. Then the left-hand side is the coefficient of $x$ in $(x-1)(x-2) \dots (x-p+1)$ - which is pretty much what Thomas Andrews just posted

Comment: I still don't understand why the condition $(a,b)=1$ is given. Maybe just to denote they are integers?

Comment: @chubakueno If we replace $a,b$ by $p^2 a$ and $p^2 b$ the problem is too easy

Comment: @Cocopuffs True, but that spoils the fun.

Answer (score 14):

Let $f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-(p-1))$. Now, by Fermat, we know that the coefficients of $f(x)$ other than the $x^{p-1}$ and $x^0$ are divisible by $p$.

So if  $f(x)=x^{p-1} + \sum_{i=0}^{p-2} a_i x^{i}$ and $p\geq 5$ then $p\mid a_2$, so  $$f(p)\equiv a_1p + a_0\pmod {p^3}$$

But we see that $f(x)=(-1)^{p-1}f(p-x)$ for any $x$, so if $p$ is odd, $f(p)=f(0)=a_0$, so that means that:

$$0=f(p)-a_0 \equiv a_1p\pmod {p^3}$$

So $0\equiv a_1\pmod{p^2}$.

Now your sum is just $\frac{a_1}{(p-1)!}$.

Comment: Great proof! I was on this problem for almost a day and I finally solved it. I found your proof when I searched for it on MSE and it is amazing. I have posted my proof also. I hope you can find time to have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you please explain how we getting $p|a_2$? I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

Write this as $\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \frac{p}{j(p-j)}.$ Then it suffices to show that 
$\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \frac{1}{j^{2}}$ is a rational number with numerator divisible by $p.$ Working (mod $p$), twice this last quantity is $\sum_{j=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{j^{2}},$ which (mod $p$) is the same as $\sum_{j=1}^{p-1} j^{2} = \frac{(p-1)p(2p-1)}{6},$ and this is $0$ mod $p$ for $p \geq 5.$

Comment: Nicely direct. I think our answers complement each other nicely.

Comment: (Except the "twice this quantity" part - which should really be about stated as a statement in $\mathbb Z_p$ - not literally true in the rationals.)

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Agreed on both points.

Answer (score 4):

Lets call $s:=(p-1)!(1 +\frac{1}{2} +\cdots +\frac{1}{p-1})$

Since, $s$ contains a even number of terms.
For $i =1,2, \dots, \frac{p-1}{2}$ and let's add them as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{i} + \frac{1}{p-i}= \frac{p}{i(p-i)} \quad \text{for} \quad i =1,2, \dots , \frac{(p-1)}{2}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
s = (p-1)! \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\frac{p}{i(p-i)}
\end{equation*}

Cleary $p$ divides $s$.

Let $t$ be defined by:
\begin{equation*}
t=(p-1)!\left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\frac{1}{i(p-i)} \right)
\end{equation*}

To prove that $t\equiv 0 \quad (\text{mod $p$})$.
Passing to $\text{mod $p$}$, and using Wilson's Theorem one obtains:
\begin{equation*}
t \equiv -\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\frac{1}{i(p-i)}=\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\frac{1}{i^2} =\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}i^2=\frac{(p-1)p(2p-1)}{6}
\end{equation*}
which is clearly divisible by 2.

Answer (score 2):

My solution below is not as elegant as that of @ThomasAndrews and is similar to that of @GeoffRobinson. I hope it adds to the understanding of the reader.

The problem is equivalent to showing the following

> For a prime $p\geq 5$, the sum $1^{-1}+ 2^{-1}+ \cdots + (p-2)^{-1}+ (p-1)^{-1}$ is $0$ in $\mathbf Z/p^2\mathbf Z$.

We prove this as follows: For each $1\leq i\leq p-1$, write $a_i$ to denote $i^{-1}$. Then note that for each $1\leq i\leq p-1$, $(p+i)^{-1}$ is $a_i+pk_i$ for some integer $k_i$. We show that $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} k_i$ is divisible by $p$.

To see that, note that we have $(p+i)(a_i+pk_i)\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$. Using $ia_i\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$, we get $p(a_i+ik_i)\equiv 0\pmod{p^2}$. This is equivalent to $a_i+ik_i\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Multiplying both sides by $a_i$, and using $ia_i\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, we have $a_i^2+k_i\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Thus $$\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}k_i\equiv -\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}a_i^2 \equiv -\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}i^2\pmod{p}$$

But $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}i^2$ is divisible by $p$ if $p\geq 5$, so the last congruence is $0$.

What we have shown is that

> $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (p+i)^{-1}$ in $\mathbf Z/p^2\mathbf Z$.

More generally one can show that

> $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (pt+i)^{-1}$ in $\mathbf Z/p^2\mathbf Z$, for any integer $t$.

So if we write $s$ for $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}i^{-1}$, we have, by putting $t=p-1$ in the above, that

$$s = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}(p(p-1)+i)^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}(-i)^{-1}=-\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}i^{-1}=-s$$

Showing $s=-s$ in $\mathbf Z/p^2\mathbf Z$, and thus $s=0$ in $\mathbf Z/p^2\mathbf Z$.