# Prove that $a$ is divisible by $p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p-1}=\frac{a}{b}$, where $a,b$ are positive integers, then prove that $a$ is divisible by $p$. Here $p$ is an odd prime.

Now, $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p-1}=\frac{t}{(p-1)!}$ where $t=(p-1)! \times (1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p-1}).$

Also, by Wilson's theorem, $(p-1)!\equiv -1 \mod p$.

But doing all above is not taking me anywhere. Can someone please help me out with the problem?

Comment: Related $\;-\;$ [Write $1/1 + 1/2 + ...1/ (p-1)=a/b$ with $(a,b)=1$. Show that $p^2 \mid a$ if $p\geq 5$ is prime [Wolstenholme's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520381/write-1-1-1-2-1-p-1-a-b-with-a-b-1-show-that-p2-mid-a-if-p).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If for a prime p $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots + \frac{1}{p-1}=\frac{a}{b}$ then show that p divides a. Moreover if $p&gt;3$ then $p^2$ divides a.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318510/if-for-a-prime-p-1-frac12-frac13-ldots-frac1p-1-fracab) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%241%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%2B%5Ccdots%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bp-1%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: FYI, there are also other basic duplicates here, e.g., such as that in dxiv's comment, [Proof of Wolstenholme's theorem](/q/325491/602049) (that my proposed duplicate is currently closed as a duplicate of), [Divisibility of a summation by $p^2$](/q/1807382/602049), [$1 + \frac {1}{2}+\frac {1}{3} +..... +\frac {1}{p-1} = \frac {a}{b}$, prove that $a$ is divisible by $p$.](/q/1153882/602049), [$1+\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3} +...+\frac{1}{p-1} =\frac{a}{b}$](/q/1256032/602049), etc.

Answer (score 1):

By the [Wolstenholme's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem), we have
$$\binom{2p-1}{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod {p^3}$$
for any prime $p\ge 5$.

A proof of the asked statement can be found [here](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Etchoi/notes/wolstenholme.pdf).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).